# Ajax, Request Header UTF-8 to ISO Charset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, utf-8

I have a page which is encoded iso-8959-9. Im sending ajax requests to same page while saving some data to DB. But its converts the chars to utf-8.
My response header  seems good with charset iso-8859-9. But the Request Header, Content-Type data always UTF-8. please refer to screenshot below.
Here is what ive done to solve this:

1- I set php header iso-8859-9

2- I changed apache's default charset to iso.

3- i set ajax options beforeSend, setRequestHeader and contentType as iso.

4- i modified jquery.js and set ajax default encoding as iso.

none of them didnt solve my problem. i dont want to do any php charset encoding btw.
Any other ideas ?

Thanks

[image]

my ajax code:
`

```
                $.ajax({

                    url: window.location.href,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-9",


                    success: function(result) {

                        $('#IcerikContent').html($(result).find("#Icerik"));
                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
                        Metronic.initAjax();
                        if (typeof initialize == 'function') { initialize(); }
                        stopPageLoading();
                    }
                });
        `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that AJAX POST requests **must** use UTF-8. The [jQuery manual explains it](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server):

> POST data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset, per the W3C XMLHTTPRequest standard.

You might now wonder about the `contentType` setting:

> Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.

In other words, you have no choice. You either need to migrate your server-side code to UTF-8, make an explicit conversion —`iconv()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` will come in handy— or figure out a witty JavaScript trick (such as serialising data before submission).

Comment: hmm. you are right. Thanks your your answer! i have to use some server side encoding things to get over from this.